# There is problem installing mysql using command prompt , for django

Tags: mysql, django, pip

After doing `pip install mysqlclient`, following problem arises, and red warning arises saying:

> [Failed building wheel for mysqlclient].
>
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

[image]

Comment: Image in the above link

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `setuptools`

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

If not insist to build by yourself, another option is to install prebuilt mysqlclient, see this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient).

Download the version you needed, for you, you can choose `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` as seems you are using 32bit python3.7.

After download it to local, use next to install it:

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

Comment: where should i keep those downloaded files?

Comment: Download to any location in your local pc. E.g. `C:/packages/mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`, then open cmd, cd to `C:/packages/`, execute `pip install mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl`.